# AWS elasticbeanstalk with django isn't Working

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: awsbeanstalk]]

[image]

[image]
I've never used an AWS Beanstalk before, and I get this error, and when I actually get to the address, the "502 badgateway" error is executed
 how can I solve this problem?(I'm using django)

`Edit`
I also downloaded the log and those are the errors
`eb_engine.log`

```
2020/07/13 02:49:45.963964 [ERROR] /usr/bin/id: healthd: no such user
2020/07/13 02:49:46.338947 [ERROR] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/healthd.service to /etc/systemd/system/healthd.service.
2020/07/13 02:49:46.746061 [ERROR] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/cfn-hup.service to 
/etc/systemd/system/cfn-hup.service.
2020/07/13 02:50:26.754823 [ERROR] Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
2020/07/13 02:50:28.038589 [ERROR] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/eb-app.target to /etc/systemd/system/eb-app.target.
2020/07/13 02:50:28.121446 [ERROR] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/web.service to /etc/systemd/system/web.service.
2020/07/13 02:50:28.171612 [ERROR] nginx: the configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
```

`nginx error`

```
2020/07/13 03:00:43 [error] 3758#0: *140 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "52.79.129.169"
2020/07/13 03:02:41 [error] 3758#0: *162 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.51, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "13.209.157.1"
2020/07/13 03:15:07 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
2020/07/13 03:15:08 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
2020/07/13 03:15:08 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
2020/07/13 03:15:08 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
2020/07/13 03:15:08 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
2020/07/13 03:15:08 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
2020/07/13 03:15:09 [error] 3758#0: *347 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.sewontax.com"
```

`daemon`

```
error (Invalid timestamp): {:id=>"0", :namespace=>"application", :timestamp=>1594609370, :data=>"{\"duration\":10,\"latency_histogram\":[[0.0,1]],\"http_counters\":{\"status_502\":1,\"request_count\":1}}"}
```

Comment: Can you go to logs of your EB env, download them, and look for any errors?

Comment: Actually I'm new in AWS, so can you tell me how to do that please? So sorry.

Comment: In the screenshots you have Events. On the left, you should find a menu withs options such as  Health, Logs, Configurations. So go to Logs, and then you will be able to requests the logs and download them.

Comment: @Marcin I downloaded the log. Among these which one should I look for?

Comment: Start from those in the main folder, such as eb-engine, cloud*, . Just quick search for key wards like error, command failed, or anything specific to your application.

Comment: @marcin I edited it. but still I don't know How to fix my problem 

Comment: Please ssh to the EC2 instance where code is deployed. PIng the below IPs and verify whether the hosts are reachable. host: "52.79.129.169", host: "13.209.157.1"

Comment: @EdwardsNick Did you ever manage to fix this problem?